# Parameter sending to SSAS from asp.net

Tags: ssas, ssrs-2012

From aspx page, I am trying to send the parameter to SSAS in the format `[DimLocation].[Location ID].&[1012]`. but when I look at the profiler for the query the "&" gets changed to `[DimLocation].[Location ID].&amp;[1012]` and the query execution fails. How to retain the ampersand sign

Comment: I don't know the syntax for SSAS, but if you don't know what to try looking up, what you're describing is a way to escape special characters..

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to review a code sample but likely you just need to change your MDX query to do StrToMember:

```
WHERE (
 StrToMember(@Location,CONSTRAINED)
)
```